# Two's Complement Binary in Python?

Tags: python, binary, bit-manipulation

Integers in Python are stored in two's complement, correct?

Although:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> bin(x)
0b101
```

And:

```
>>> x = -5
>>> bin(x)
-0b101
```

That's pretty lame. How do I get python to give me the numbers in REAL binary bits, and without the 0b infront of it? So:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> bin(x)
0101
>>> y = -5
>>> bin(y)
1011
```

Comment: How it's stored is an implementation detail.

Comment: [Thanks Two, that's very nice of you!](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/compliment-versus-complement.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [two's complement of numbers in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871829/twos-complement-of-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how to get what you want using the standard lib.  There are a handful of scripts and packages out there that will do the conversion for you.

I just wanted to note the "why" , and why it's not lame.

bin() doesn't return binary bits. it converts the number to a binary string.  the leading '0b' tells the interpreter that you're dealing with a binary number , as per the python language definition.  this way you can directly work with binary numbers, like this

```
>>> 0b01
1
>>> 0b10
2
>>> 0b11
3
>>> 0b01 + 0b10
3
```

that's not lame. that's great.

---

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#bin

> bin(x)
>
> > Convert an integer number to a binary string.

http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integers

> Integer and long integer literals are described by the following lexical definitions:
>
> > bininteger     ::=  "0" ("b" | "B") bindigit+
> >
> > bindigit       ::=  "0" | "1"

Answer (score 99):

It works best if you provide a mask. That way you specify how far to sign extend.

```
>>> bin(-27 & 0b1111111111111111)
'0b1111111111100101'
```

Or perhaps more generally:

```
def bindigits(n, bits):
    s = bin(n & int("1"*bits, 2))[2:]
    return ("{0:0>%s}" % (bits)).format(s)

>>> print bindigits(-31337, 24)
111111111000010110010111
```

In basic theory, the actual width of the number is a function of the size of the storage. If it's a 32-bit number, then a negative number has a 1 in the MSB of a set of 32. If it's a 64-bit value, then there are 64 bits to display.

But in Python, integer precision is limited only to the constraints of your hardware. On my computer, this *actually works*, but it consumes 9GB of RAM just to store the value of **x**. Anything higher and I get a MemoryError. If I had more RAM, I could store larger numbers.

```
>>> x = 1 << (1 << 36)
```

So with that in mind, what binary number represents `-1`? Python is well-capable of interpreting literally millions (and even billions) of bits of precision, as the previous example shows. In 2's complement, the sign bit extends all the way to the left, but in Python there is no pre-defined number of bits; there are as many as you need.

But then you run into ambiguity: does binary `1` represent `1`, or `-1`? Well, it could be either. Does `111` represent `7` or `-1`? Again, it could be either. So does `111111111` represent `511`, or `-1`... well, both, depending on your precision.

Python needs a way to represent these numbers in binary so that there's no ambiguity of their meaning. The `0b` prefix just says "this number is in binary". Just like `0x` means "this number is in hex". So if I say `0b1111`, how do I know if the user wants -1 or 15? There are two options:

**Option A:** *The sign bit*
You could declare that all numbers are signed, and the left-most bit is the  sign bit. That means `0b1` is -1, while `0b01` is 1. That also means that `0b111` is also -1, while `0b0111` is 7. In the end, this is probably more confusing than helpful particularly because **most binary arithmetic is going to be unsigned anyway,** and people are more likely to run into mistakes by accidentally marking a number as negative because they didn't include an explicit sign bit.

**Option B:** *The sign indication*
With this option, binary numbers are represented unsigned, and negative numbers have a "-" prefix, just like they do in decimal. This is (a) more consistent with decimal, (b) more compatible with the way binary values are most likely going to be used. You lose the ability to specify a negative number using its two's complement representation, but remember that two's complement is a *storage implementation* detail, not a proper indication of the underlying value itself. It shouldn't have to be something that the user has to understand.

In the end, Option B makes the most sense. There's less confusion and the user isn't required to understand the storage details.

Comment: +1, for the purpose of generating a printed representation, this is the simplest approach. (Keep in mind, though, that the actual result of `-27 & 0b111111111` is a positive number in memory!)

Comment: @senderle it's only a positive number if most significant bit is 0. How many bits are there? Well, that's what you decide with your mask. If you decide that you're limited to 16 bits, then for your purposes this the 16th bit specifies the sign. Plain and simple.

Comment: Right, but my point is simply that _in memory_, the most significant bit in the value that results from `-27 & 0b11111111` is a zero. (More generally, the result of `&` will always be positive if one of the operands is positive, because a positive value is understood to be preceded by an [infinite string of zeros](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).)

Comment: `bin(-12 & int('0b' + '1' * 16, 2))` for the lazy.

Comment: Anyone can elaborate on the "Option A"?
Once I got that this is indeed my case, how do I convert a negative binary number to decimal?

Comment: thanks. use this method,I can print any bit restrict for negative number's  two's complement.  suppose you wanna get the binary number of -9, however, if you specify the max bit is 5. you can perform  ```bin(-9 & 0b11111)```. and get ```0b10111```.

Comment: I understand the reasoning and all this make sense, but it doesn't remove the fact that it is _plain inconvenient_ to see "negative" binary number notation, something that doesn't actually exist. Specially when you want to do bitwise operations. `bin(re.UNICODE) == '0b100000'` (should be `00100000`) but `bin(~re.UNICODE) == '-0b100001'` (should be `11011111`)... Try to explain that to a Jr. developer...

Answer (score 17):

To properly interpret a binary sequence as two's complement, there needs to a length associated with the sequence. When you are working low-level types that correspond directly to CPU registers, there is an implicit length. Since Python integers can have an arbitrary length, there really isn't an internal two's complement format. Since there isn't a length associated with a number, there is no way to distinguish between positive and negative numbers. To remove the ambiguity, bin() includes a minus sign when formatting a negative number.

Python's arbitrary length integer type actually uses a sign-magnitude internal format. The logical operations (bit shifting, and, or, etc.) are designed to mimic two's complement format. This is typical of multiple precision libraries.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a little bit more readable version of [Tylerl answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946116/twos-complement-binary-in-python/12946226#12946226), for example let's say you want **-2** in its **8-bits** negative representation of "two's complement" :

```
bin(-2 & (2**8-1))
```

2**8 stands for the ninth bit (256), substract 1 to it and you have all the preceding bits set to one (255)

for 8 and 16 bits masks, you can replace (2**8-1) by 0xff, or 0xffff. The hexadecimal version becomes less readalbe after that point.

If this is unclear, here is a regular function of it:

```
def twosComplement (value, bitLength) :
    return bin(value & (2**bitLength - 1))
```

Answer (score 6):

The compliment of one minus number's meaning is  **mod value minus the positive value**.
So I think，the brief way for the compliment of -27 is

```
bin((1<<32) - 27)  // 32 bit length  '0b11111111111111111111111111100101'
bin((1<<16) - 27)
bin((1<<8) - 27)   // 8 bit length  '0b11100101'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tobin = lambda x, count=8: "".join(map(lambda y:str((x>>y)&1), range(count-1, -1, -1)))
```

e.g.

```
tobin(5)      # =>  '00000101'
tobin(5, 4)   # =>      '0101'
tobin(-5, 4)  # =>      '1011'
```

Or as clear functions:

```
# Returns bit y of x (10 base).  i.e. 
# bit 2 of 5 is 1
# bit 1 of 5 is 0
# bit 0 of 5 is 1
def getBit(y, x):
    return str((x>>y)&1)

# Returns the first `count` bits of base 10 integer `x`
def tobin(x, count=8):
    shift = range(count-1, -1, -1)
    bits = map(lambda y: getBit(y, x), shift)
    return "".join(bits)
```

(Adapted from [W.J. Van de Laan's](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/219300-format-integer-as-binary-string) comment)

Answer (score 3):

Use slices to get rid of unwanted '0b'.

> > > `bin(5)[2:]`
> > >       '101'

or if you want digits,

> > > `tuple ( bin(5)[2:] )`
> > >       ('1', '0', '1')

or even

> > > `map( int, tuple( bin(5)[2:] ) )`
> > >       [1, 0, 1]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help when the number goes negative and you get a bogus negative to deal with as well.

"-0b" gets prepended.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely certain what you ultimately want to do, but you might want to look at the [bitarray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) package.

Answer (score 2):

```
def tobin(data, width):
    data_str = bin(data & (2**width-1))[2:].zfill(width)
    return data_str
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Binary fractions](https://pypi.org/project/binary-fractions/) package. This package implements `TwosComplement` with binary integers and binary fractions. You can convert binary-fraction strings into their twos complement and vice-versa

Example:

```
>>> from binary_fractions import TwosComplement
>>> TwosComplement.to_float("11111111111") # TwosComplement --> float
-1.0
>>> TwosComplement.to_float("11111111100") # TwosComplement --> float
-4.0
>>> TwosComplement(-1.5) # float --> TwosComplement
'10.1'
>>> TwosComplement(1.5) # float --> TwosComplement
'01.1'
>>> TwosComplement(5) # int --> TwosComplement
'0101'
```

To use this with Binary's instead of float's you can use the `Binary` class inside the same package.

PS: Shameless plug, I'm the author of this package.

Answer (score 1):

For positive numbers, just use:

```
bin(x)[2:].zfill(4)
```

For negative numbers, it's a little different:

```
bin((eval("0b"+str(int(bin(x)[3:].zfill(4).replace("0","2").replace("1","0").replace("2","1"))))+eval("0b1")))[2:].zfill(4)
```

As a whole script, this is how it should look:

```
def binary(number):
    if number < 0:
        return bin((eval("0b"+str(int(bin(number)[3:].zfill(4).replace("0","2").replace("1","0").replace("2","1"))))+eval("0b1")))[2:].zfill(4)
    return bin(number)[2:].zfill(4)      
x=input()
print binary(x)
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the requested result for negative numbers. The result should be `1011`, not `101`.

Comment: Well, now it gives wrong results for other numbers. `binary(-4)` should be something like `1100` or `11111100`, but this gives `11`, which is totally wrong.

Comment: oh, my mistake, the program now uses two's compliment

Answer (score 1):

A modification on tylerl's very helpful answer that provides sign extension for positive numbers as well as negative (no error checking).

```
def to2sCompStr(num, bitWidth):
    num &= (2 << bitWidth-1)-1 # mask
    formatStr = '{:0'+str(bitWidth)+'b}'
    ret =  formatStr.format(int(num))
    return ret
```

Example:

```
In [11]: to2sCompStr(-24, 18)
Out[11]: '111111111111101000'

In [12]: to2sCompStr(24, 18)
Out[12]: '000000000000011000'
```

Answer (score 1):

No need, it already is. It is just python choosing to represent it differently. If you start printing each nibble separately, it will show its true colours.

```
checkNIB = '{0:04b}'.format
checkBYT = lambda x: '-'.join( map( checkNIB, [ (x>>4)&0xf, x&0xf] ) ) 
checkBTS = lambda x: '-'.join( [ checkBYT( ( x>>(shift*8) )&0xff ) for shift in reversed( range(4) ) if ( x>>(shift*8) )&0xff ] )


print( checkBTS(-0x0002) )
```

Output is simple:

```
>>>1111-1111-1111-1111-1111-1111-1111-1110
```

Now it reverts to original representation when you want to display a twos complement of an nibble but it is still possible if you divide it into halves of nibble and so. **Just have in mind that the best result is with negative hex and binary integer interpretations** simple numbers not so much, also with **hex** you can set up the byte size.

Answer (score 0):

We can leverage the property of bit-wise XOR. Use bit-wise XOR to flip the bits and then add 1. Then you can use the python inbuilt bin() function to get the binary representation of the 2's complement. Here's an example function:

```
def twos_complement(input_number):
    print(bin(input_number))                            # prints binary value of input
    mask = 2**(1 + len(bin(input_number)[2:])) - 1      # Calculate mask to do bitwise XOR operation
    twos_comp = (input_number ^ mask) + 1               # calculate 2's complement, for negative of input_number (-1 * input_number)
    print(bin(twos_comp))                               # print 2's complement representation of negative of input_number.
```

Answer (score -3):

**I hope this solves your problem**`

```
num = input("Enter number : ")
bin_num=bin(num)
binary = '0' + binary_num[2:]
print binary
```

Comment: Question is about having an U2 representation of a number so for -1 (if 4 bytes used to encode it) it should be 0xffffff (or equivalent in binary). Your solution wouldn't work