# Python representation of negative integers

Tags: python, integer, bit-manipulation

```
>>> x = -4
>>> print("{} {:b}".format(x, x))
-4 -100
>>> mask = 0xFFFFFFFF
>>> print("{} {:b}".format(x & mask, x & mask))
4294967292 11111111111111111111111111111100
>>> 
>>> x = 0b11111111111111111111111111111100
>>> print("{} {:b}".format(x, x))
4294967292 11111111111111111111111111111100
>>> print("{} {:b}".format(~(x ^ mask), ~(x ^ mask)))
-4 -100
```

I am having trouble figuring out how Python represents negative integers, and therefore how bit operations work. It is my understanding that Python attempts to emulate two's complement, but with any number of bits. Therefore, it is common to use 32-bit masks to force Python to set a standard size on integers before bit operations.

As you can see in my example, `-4 & 0xFFFFFFFF` yields a large positive number. Why does Python seem to read this as an unsigned integer, instead of a two's complement negative number? Later, the operation `~(x ^ mask)`, which should yield the exact same two's complement bit pattern as the large positive, instead gives `-4`. What causes the conversion to a signed int?

Thanks!

Comment: When you're dealing with arbitrary-length 2's-complement integers, the sign bit is notionally an infinite distance to the left.  AND with a positive number will always give a positive result, because none of the 1 bits in that positive number can possibly be the sign bit.

Comment: @jasonharper so anytime I work with a negative integer, I should treat it as if it extends infinitely to the left? And using a 32-bit mask is just to make it easier to think about as long as I unmask it in the end?

Comment: note: it is not how CPython represents `int` objects internally. It uses [`sys.int_info.bits_per_digit` (30) bits per digit](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/0b3fe61c553544d707a144a90f9e65b144ce2f59/Include/longintrepr.h#L70-L88).

Comment: A Python 3 integer is represented internally as an array of digits of base 2^30 with the sign stored separately. That is how it does integer arithmetic of arbitrary precision. So internally it is quite different from a C `long` or `long long`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format negative integers in two's complement representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255496/format-negative-integers-in-twos-complement-representation)

Answer (score 18):

TLDR; CPython integer type stores the sign in a specific field of a structure. When performing a bitwise operation, CPython replaces negative numbers by their two's complement and *sometimes* (!) performs the reverse operation (ie replace the two's complements by negative numbers).

## Bitwise operations

The internal representation of an integer is a `PyLongObject` struct, that contains a `PyVarObject` struct. (When CPython creates a new `PyLong` object, it allocates the memory for the structure and a trailing space for the digits.) What matter here is that the `PyLong` is sized: the `ob_size` field of the `PyVarObject` embedded struct contains the size (in digits) of the integer (digits are either 15 or 30 bits digits).
If the integer is negative then this size is *minus* the number of digits .

*(References: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/object.h and https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/longobject.h)*

As you see, the inner CPython's representation of an integer is really far from the usual binary representation. Yet CPython has to provide bitwise operations for various purposes. Let's take a look at the comments in [the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L4567):

```
static PyObject *
long_bitwise(PyLongObject *a,
             char op,  /* '&', '|', '^' */
             PyLongObject *b)
{
    /* Bitwise operations for negative numbers operate as though
       on a two's complement representation.  So convert arguments
       from sign-magnitude to two's complement, and convert the
       result back to sign-magnitude at the end. */

    /* If a is negative, replace it by its two's complement. */
    /* Same for b. */
    /* Complement result if negative. */
}
```

To handle negative integers in bitwise operations, CPython use the two's complement (actually, that's a two's complement digit by digit, but I don't go into the details). But note the **"Sign Rule"** (name is mine): the sign of the result is the bitwise operator applied to the signs of the numbers. More precisely, the result is negative if `nega <op> negb == 1`, (`negx` = `1` for negative, `0` for positive). [Simplified code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L4626):

```
switch (op) {
    case '^': negz = nega ^ negb; break;
    case '&': negz = nega & negb; break;
    case '|': negz = nega | negb; break;
    default: ...
}
```

## Binary formatting

On the other hand, the formatter does not perform the two's complement, even in binary representation: [format_long_internal](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/formatter_unicode.c#L839) calls [long_format_binary](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L1934) and remove the two leading characters, but keeps the sign. See [the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/formatter_unicode.c#L966):

```
 /* Is a sign character present in the output?  If so, remember it
           and skip it */
        if (PyUnicode_READ_CHAR(tmp, inumeric_chars) == '-') {
            sign_char = '-';
            ++prefix;
            ++leading_chars_to_skip;
}
```

The `long_format_binary` function does not perform any two's complement: just output the number in base 2, [preceded by the sign](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/longobject.c#L2048).

```
    if (negative)                                                   \
        *--p = '-'; \
```

## Your question

I will follow your REPL sequence:

```
>>> x = -4
>>> print("{} {:b}".format(x, x))
-4 -100
```

Nothing surprising, given that there is no two's complement in formatting, but a sign.

```
>>> mask = 0xFFFFFFFF
>>> print("{} {:b}".format(x & mask, x & mask))
4294967292 11111111111111111111111111111100
```

The number `-4` is negative. Hence, it is replaced by its two's complement before the logical and, digit by digit. You expected that the result will be turned into a negative number, but remember the "Sign Rule":

```
>>> nega=1; negb=0
>>> nega & negb
0
```

Hence: 1. the result does not have the negative sign; 2. the result is not complemented to two. Your result is compliant with the "Sign Rule", even if this rule doesn't seem very intuitive.

Now, the last part:

```
>>> x = 0b11111111111111111111111111111100
>>> print("{} {:b}".format(x, x))
4294967292 11111111111111111111111111111100
>>> print("{} {:b}".format(~(x ^ mask), ~(x ^ mask)))
-4 -100
```

Again, `-4` is negative, hence replaced by it's two's complement `0b11111111111111111111111111111100`, then XORed with `0b11111111111111111111111111111111`. The result is `0b11` (`3`). You take the complement unary, that is `0b11111111111111111111111111111100` again, but this time the sign is negative:

```
>>> nega=1; negb=0
>>> nega ^ negb
1
```

Therefore, the result is complemented and gets the negative sign, as you expected.

Conclusion: I guess there was no perfect solution to have arbitrary long signed number **and** provide bitwise operations, but the documentation is not really verbose on the choices that were made.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't specify a internal number representation for signed integers (like two's complement, sign-magnitude, etc.).  Different implementations of Python like CPython, IronPython, PyPy, etc. can do different things.  Hence going with the manual is a better bet as it's a language-level guarantee than depending on one particular implementation's behaviour.

The answer to both your questions is quite simple when you read the manual [§ Bitwise Operations on Integer Types](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types) (emphasis mine):

> The result of bitwise operations is calculated as though carried out in **two’s complement with an infinite number of sign bits**.

Two important [rules of converting two's complement to decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Converting_to_two%27s_complement_representation) before we proceed:

1. MSB decides the sign; negative if set
2. magnitude = magnitude if MSB unset else two's complement(magnitude)

```py
 4 = 0b0..0_0100  # Notice infinite 0s preceding as 4 is +ve
~4 = 0b1..1_1011  # Notice infinite 1s preceding (MSB set)
```

We can't work with infinity easily, let's assume a 4-bit representation.  So `~4` is `0b1011`; this is `-5` in two's complement.  Why?  Recall rules of working with two's complement above: negative as MSB is set, magnitude = two's complement(`0b1011`) = `100 + 1 = 101 = 5`.  `-5` stays the same even with a wider type e.g. as 8-bit `0b1111_1011` two's complement is `-5`.  This works at any widths wider than 4's binary representation.

> `-4 & 0xFFFFFFFF` yields a large positive number. Why does Python seem to read this as an unsigned integer, instead of a two's complement negative number?

Python does represent `-4` as two's complement *but* with infinite sign bit extension.  `-4` in two's complement 8-bit representation: `0b1111_1100`.  Let's do the bitwise `AND` remembering our infinite sign bit extension:

```py
0b1..1_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1100  # -4 two's complement in ∞-bit repr
0b0..0_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111  # 0xffff_ffff in ∞-bit repr
#----------------------------------------------  &
0b0..0_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1100
#----------------------------------------------
```

The result of `-4 & 0xffff_ffff` is the infinite sign bits preceding are cut off by the mask: you get `4294967292`.

> the operation `~(x ^ mask)`, which should yield the exact same two's complement bit pattern as the large positive, instead gives `-4`. What causes the conversion to a signed int?

`x ^ mask` = `0b1..100 ^ 0b1..111` = `3`.  `~3 = -4` due to the same rules I've explained above.

In Python bitwise complement is going to flip the sign as the MSB too gets flipped.  Bitwise AND with a mask to always get a positive value; to force it into a positive value irrespective of the operand's sign.