# Is there any built-in function to get the binary format of a negative integer in Python?

Tags: python, binary, integer

```
>>> bin(-1)
'-0b1'
```

bin() function returns '-' and '0b' and the absolute value of the input negative number. (I knew that python will suffer underflow, but it will never overflow.) **Is that how python store a negative number?** Store negative sign and its absolute value? Where is the sign bit in Python?

If I input:

```
int('1000..(many many zeros)..0000',2)
```

**No matter how many zeros, the '1' on the head will never be regard as minus sign bit?** 
Therefore, does that mean the relationship between binary and integer isn't the same as that in C++? I am confused with the original binary rules in python.

Comment: Have you tried to find something along the line of two's complement in Python? https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators has a fair bit of good information and explanation

Comment: Check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255496/format-negative-integers-in-twos-complement-representation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format negative integers in two's complement representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255496/format-negative-integers-in-twos-complement-representation)

Answer (score -1):

Numbers in python have arbitrary range. But, given a word size, you can get the usual two-complemente word:

```
def two_comp(x, n):
    return bin(2**n+x)[-n:]
```