# Bitwise not operator doesn't flip bits

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, bitwise-not

I am trying to use the bitwise not operator to flip the bits in 1.

I start with 1 (00000001) and add ~.

```
x = ~1
print(f'{x:08b}')
```

Result is -0000010.

Everything online tells me the result should be 11111110. Not sure what I can do wrong with putting ~ in front of a number.

I tried adding a step to make sure 1 shows up as 00000001, and it did:

```
a = 1
print(f'{a:08b}')
x = ~a
print(f'{x:08b}')
```

Really not sure how I can go wrong on this...

Comment: Looks like x is a byte so flipping a bit in a byte will give you -10b or -2

Comment: How can I ensure my number is a bit and not a byte in that case?

Comment: Actually I'm wrong. @Kache is right

Comment: Due to Python's infinite-precision integers, -2 would be represented as an infinite number of ones: 111....1110.  Use masking to get the number of ones you want: `x = ~a & 0xff` -> `11111110`.

Comment: `'{0:08b}'.format(0xffff & ~1)`
`'1111111111111110'`

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations

> The unary ~ (invert) operator yields the bitwise inversion of its integer argument. The bitwise inversion of x is defined as -(x+1).

So it's behaving as expected, printing "negative-of-a positive 2's complement". It doesn't print in 2's complement negative because: [Format negative integers in two's complement representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255496/format-negative-integers-in-twos-complement-representation)

Comment: So how do I get the inverse of my bits as I want?

I'm looking at this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-tilde-work) and the top answers also manage to flip numbers by using the tilde. Why does that not work here?

Comment: you mean this `print(f'{x & 0xFF:08b}')`?

Comment: That's it! Why do I not get that by just using ~1?

Comment: Because you can't print an infinite number of 1s easily :)

Comment: That would indeed be rather tiresome, to watch an infinite number of 1's appear on my screen!

But I thought bits were specifically 8 binary spaces only. How come this is infinite?

(Sorry, just starting out, very confused and learning on my own so no one else I can ask!)

Comment: Python integers are infinite precision.  Without a mask it doesn't know how many bits to print, so it prints the negative value if the number is negative.  The mask makes the number positive and limits the number of bits in the result.

Comment: A bit is one "binary space" and a byte is 8 bits. But as @MarkTolonen says, a Python integer can be made of arbitrarily many bytes.

Comment: I see. I'm reading about the operators but I suppose I should look into masks first, mayhap. Thanks for explaining!