# two's complement of numbers in python

Tags: python, twos-complement

I am writing code that will have negative and positive numbers all 16 bits long with the MSB being the sign aka two's complement. This means the smallest number I can have is **-32768** which is `1000 0000 0000 0000` in two's complement form. The largest number I can have is **32767** which is `0111 1111 1111 1111`.

The issue I am having is python is representing the negative numbers with the same binary notation as positive numbers just putting a minus sign out the front i.e. **-16384** is displayed as `-0100 0000 0000 0000` what I want to be displayed for a number like **-16384** is `1100 0000 0000 0000`.

I am not quite sure how this can be coded. This is the code i have. Essentially if the number is between 180 and 359 its going to be negative. I need to display this as a twos compliment value. I dont have any code on how to display it because i really have no idea how to do it.

```
def calculatebearingActive(i):

    numTracks = trackQty_Active
    bearing = (((i)*360.0)/numTracks)
    if 0< bearing <=179:
        FC = (bearing/360.0)
        FC_scaled = FC/(2**(-16))
        return int(FC_scaled)

    elif 180<= bearing <=359:
        FC = -1*(360-bearing)/(360.0)
        FC_scaled = FC/(2**(-16))
        return int(FC_scaled)

    elif bearing ==360:
        FC = 0
        return FC
```

Comment: Are you concerned with displaying only or do you also want to perform calculations?

Comment: It's pretty hard to find your bug without seeing your code.

Comment: why do you insist on editing 'complement' to 'compliment'?

Comment: Why don't you use an actual 16-bit numeric type? Numpy has them.

Comment: related: [Two's Complement in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1604464/4279)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're doing something like

```
format(num, '016b')
```

to convert your numbers to a two's complement string representation, you'll want to actually take the two's complement of a negative number before stringifying it:

```
format(num if num >= 0 else (1 << 16) + num, '016b')
```

or take it mod `65536`:

```
format(num % (1 << 16), '016b')
```

Comment: `format(num if num >= 0 else (1 << 16) - num, '016b')` gets '10100000000000000' for `num=-16384`, while the OP wants '1100 0000 0000 0000'

Comment: @zhangxaochen: Whoops. That `-` needs to be a `+`. Fixed.

Comment: this does exactly what i want. Thankyou so much

Comment: You can also do `format(num & 0xffff, '016b')` to do so using a bitmask.

Answer (score 2):

The two's complement of a value is the one's complement plus one.

You can write your own conversion function based on that:

```
def to_binary(value):
    result = ''
    if value < 0:
        result = '-'
        value = ~value + 1
    result += bin(value)
    return result
```

The result looks like this:

```
>>> to_binary(10)
'0b1010'
>>> to_binary(-10)
'-0b1010'
```

Edit: To display the bits without the minus in front you can use this function:

```
def to_twoscomplement(bits, value):
    if value < 0:
        value = ( 1<<bits ) + value
    formatstring = '{:0%ib}' % bits
    return formatstring.format(value)

>>> to_twoscomplement(16, 3)
'0000000000000011'
>>> to_twoscomplement(16, -3)
'1111111111111101'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to store the numbers using 16 bits, you can use struct.

```
import struct

>>> struct.pack('h', 32767)
'\xff\x7f'
>>> struct.pack('h', -32767)
'\x01\x80'
```

You can unpack using `unpack`

```
>>> a = struct.pack('h', 32767)
>>> struct.unpack('H', a)
32767
```

Comment: if an interface was going to unpack that would it see a two's compliment number? What i mean is would it know that the value packed is meant to be a negative?

Answer (score 0):

Python can hold unlimited integer values, the bit representation will adopt to hold any number you put. So such technical details as two complement does not make sense in this context. In C 'b1111111111111111' means -1 for int16 and 65535 for uint16 or int32. In python it is always is 65535 as the int will adopt to hold such values.

I think this is why they opted to add - in front of negative numbers regardless of string representation (binary, oct, hex, decimal ...).

If you wish to replicate the C behaviour and get the negative represented in two complement form you have the following options:

#### 1 int > uint > bin using numpy

The most straight forward way is to dump the value as signed limited int and read it as unsigned.

If you have access to numpy the code is pretty easy to read:

```
>>> bin(np.int16(-30).astype(np.uint16))
'0b1111111111100010'
>>> bin(np.int16(-1).astype(np.uint16))
'0b1111111111111111'
>>> bin(np.int16(-2).astype(np.uint16))
'0b1111111111111110'
>>> bin(np.int16(-16).astype(np.uint16))
'0b1111111111110000'
```

#### 2 int > uint > bin using struct

You can do the similar think with struct but it is slightly harder to understand

```
>>> bin(struct.unpack('>H', struct.pack('>h', 30))[0])
'0b1111111111100010'
>>> bin(struct.unpack('>H', struct.pack('>h', -1))[0])
'0b1111111111111111'
>>> bin(struct.unpack('>H', struct.pack('>h', -2))[0])
'0b1111111111111110'
>>> bin(struct.unpack('>H', struct.pack('>h', -16))[0])
'0b1111111111110000'
```

Note: h is signed and H is unsigned int 16, and '>' stands for bigendian it comes handy if you want to read bytes directly without converting them back to int

#### 3. int using struct, then read byte by byte and convert to bin

```
>>> ''.join(f'{byte:08b}' for byte in struct.pack('>h', -1<<15))
'1000000000000000'
>>> ''.join(f'{byte:08b}' for byte in struct.pack('>h', -1))
'1111111111111111'
>>> ''.join(f'{byte:08b}' for byte in struct.pack('>h', -2))
'1111111111111110'
>>> ''.join(f'{byte:08b}' for byte in struct.pack('>h', -16))
'1111111111110000'
```

Note this has some quirks, as you need to remember to enforce the byte binary representation to be 8 digits long with '08'.

#### 3 Directly from math,

Lastly you can go check what wikipedia says about 2 complement representation and get it implemented directly from the math formula [Two complement > Subtraction from 2N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Subtraction_from_2N)

```
>>> bin(2**16 -16)
'0b1111111111110000'
>>> bin(2**16 -3)
'0b1111111111111101'
```

This looks super simple but it is hard to understand if you are not versed in the way 2 complement representation works.

Answer (score -1):

Since you haven't given any code examples, I can't be sure what's going on.  Based on the numbers in your example, I don't think you're using `bin(yourint)` because you're output doesn't contain `0b`.  Maybe you're already slicing that off in your examples.

If you are storing your binary data as strings, you could do something like:

```
    def handle_negatives(binary_string):
        If binary_string < 0:
            binary_string = '1' + str(binary_string)[1:]
        Return binary_string
```

Answer (score -1):

Here are some caveats in printing complements(1s and 2s) in binary form, in python:

```
UNSIGNED RANGE:      0 to (2^k)-1 for k bit number 
               ex:   0 to (2^32)-1 numbers
               ex:   0 to 7 for 3 bit unsigned numbers (count = 8)

SIGNED RANGE:       -2^(k-1) to +2^(k-1)-1 for 1+k bit number (k-1 is for dividing current range k into two equal half)
               ex:  -2^31 to +(2^31)-1 numbers  
               ex   -8 to +7 for 1+3 bit signed numbers (count = 8)
```

```py
bin(int)->str converts an integer to binary string
   CAVEAT: 1. Since in python there is no limit to length of integer
           for ~x or !x (1s_complement/not/negate) we can't determine how many bits after MSB needs to be 1
           so python just prints out unsigned value of target negative number in binary format with a
           '-' sign in the beginning
           ex: for x = b'01010'(10) we get ~x = -0b'1011' (-11) 
               but we should be getting -16+5 = -11 
               (-b'10000'+b'00101') = -b'10101' (-11 signed) or (21 unsigned)
               to get real binary value after negation(or 1s complement) one could simulate it
               NOTE:  2^0 is always 1, so (2**0 == 1) in python
               NOTE:  (1 << k) is always 2^k (left shift is 2 raised to the power k)
               ex: bin((1 << k)-1 - x) which is ((2^k)-1)-x  (1s complement)
               ex: bin((1 << k)-1 - x) + 1 which is (2^k)-x  (2s complement)
          2. Same goes for reverse parsing of signed binary string to int: 
             ex: int("-0b'0101'", 2) gives -5 but instead it actually is -11 assuming -0b represents all bits 
                 from MSB till current to be like 1111......0101 which is actually -16+5 = -11
                 BUT due to PYTHON's limitation of representing signed binary values we need to adhere to 
                 current way of parsing considering unsigned binary strings with sign in front for -ve numbers
```

```py
# NOTE: how the significant prefix zeros doesn't matter in both +ve and -ve cases

# Byte type inputs
x = b'+1010'            # valid +ve number byte string
x = b'1010'             # valid +ve number byte string
x = b'-1010'            # valid -ve number byte string
x = b'+01010'           # valid +ve number byte string
x = b'01010'            # valid +ve number byte string
x = b'-01010'           # valid -ve number byte string

int(b'101')             # interprets as base 10 for each digit
int(b'101', 2)          # interprets as base 2 for each digit
int(b'101', 8)          # interprets as base 8 for each digit
int(b'101', 10)         # interprets as base 10 for each digit
int(b'101', 16)         # interprets as base 16 for each digit

# String type inputs
x = '+1010'            # valid +ve number string
x = '1010'             # valid +ve number string
x = '-1010'            # valid -ve number string
x = '+01010'           # valid +ve number string
x = '01010'            # valid +ve number string
x = '-01010'           # valid -ve number string

int('101')             # interprets as base 10 for each digit
int('101', 2)          # interprets as base 2 for each digit
int('101', 8)          # interprets as base 8 for each digit
int('101', 10)         # interprets as base 10 for each digit
int('101', 16)         # interprets as base 16 for each digit

# print(bin(int(x, 2)), int(x,2), ~int(x, 2), bin(~int(x,2)), "-"+bin((1<<k)-1 - int(x,2)))
```

```py
k = 5                   # no of bits
assert 2**0 == 1        # (2^0 is always 1)
_2k = (1 << k)          # (2^k == left shift (2^0 or 1) by k times == multiply 2 by k times)
x = '01010'             # valid +ve number string
x = int(x,2)
print("input:", x)      # supposed to be 1s complement of binStr but due to python's limitation, 
                        # we consider it -(unsigned binStr)
_1s = '-'+bin((_2k-1)-x)
print("1s complement(negate/not): ", _1s, ~x)
_2s = '-'+bin(_2k-x)
print("2s complement(1s +1):      ", _2s, ~x+1)

output:
k = 5 (5 bit representation)
input: 10
1s complement(negate/not):  -0b10101 -11
2s complement(1s +1):       -0b10110 -10

k=32 (32 bit representation)
input: 10
1s complement(negate/not):  -0b11111111111111111111111111110101 -11
2s complement(1s +1):       -0b11111111111111111111111111110110 -10
```