# bin() function in Python

Tags: python, function, binary

To represent a negative number in binary form we can use 0 or 1 as an additional digit in binary number but python return negative sign for negative number using bin function. Why it is not returning negative binary number using 0 and 1, and how can we get binary form of negative number without neagtive sign using Python:

```
>>> bin(11)
'0b1011'
>>> bin(-11)
'-0b1011'
```

Comment: You mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946116/twos-complement-binary-in-python

Comment: Please [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).