# int('10000000000000000000000000000001',2) does not return negative value

Tags: python, integer

```
>>>a='11111111111111111111111111110101'
>>>int(a,2)
4294967285
```

In the above code, I thought that 32'nd number is MSB(Most Significant Bit) and if MSB is 1,
 The value indicates negative.
but why does the int() function return positive number?

Comment: Python `int` is an arbitrary-precision type, not a 32-bit signed integer type.

Comment: Try setting `a` to `'-11111111111111111111111111110101'`

Answer (score 2):

In Python that works a bit different, it is using two complements. I think the answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946116/twos-complement-binary-in-python) is what you are looking for and answers the 'why?'. You can test that yourself by using the bin()-function which returns you the bit equivalent  of a number.

```
a='11111111111111111111111111110101'
print(int(a,2))
#4294967285

# Postive Integer 
# Same as above
b='0b11111111111111111111111111110101'
print(int(b,2))
#4294967285

# Negative Integer
=c'-0b11111111111111111111111111110101'
print(int(c,2))
#-4294967285
```